# Cup product of a wedge sum of n sphere

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For my class, I have to compute the cup product of $S^2\vee S^3\vee S^4 \vee ...\vee S^n \vee S^{n+1}=X$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients and $\mathbb{F}_2$ coefficients .

If I take $x_p\in H^p(X)\cong H^p(S^p)$ and $x_q \in H^q(X)\cong H^q(S^q)$ two generator and we write $u_k$ to be the generator of $H^k(S^k)$, then how can I deduce  $x_p \cup x_q $ from $u_p \cup u_q$.

I though of considering $S^2\vee...\vee S^{p+q-1}\vee S^{p+q+1} \vee ...\vee S^n \vee S^{n+1}=Y$ ( we forget the $S^{p+q}$ summand) and then we would have the following cofibration:
$$Y \to X \to Y$$
Where the first map is the inclusion and the second is the collapse of the $S^{p+q}$ summand on the basepoint $\alpha$ this should induce an isomorphism in cohomology but I'm not sure why.

But with that I could conlcude that the cup products are zero.

Is my reasonning right and can I have an explanation of why there is this isomorphism ?

Comment: You still have retractions, although their precise nature depends on how exactly you're wedging the spaces together. Are the spheres all wedged together at one single point or is $S^2$ wedged to $S^3$ at one point, then $S^3$ wedged to $S^4$ at another point, etc..? (To be clear, the resulting spaces are homotopy-equivalent, but for explicit understanding, it's probably best to clarify.)

Comment: @Thorgott this was also one of my concern, it is not specified but I assumed all sphere where wedge together

Comment: The composite $Y \to X \to Y$ induces an isomorphism on cohomology because the composite is the identity map on $Y$.